# MongoDB is returning all fields instead of the matching ones

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to join 2 collections with eachother with MongoDB. It does not work however the way I want.. This is what I have now:

Trying to join these 2 collections

```
//Group collection
_id:ObjectId(5fa2d687c59139213cf8c081)
groupname: : chatting

//Peoplegroups collection
_id:5fa2d687c59139213cf8c082
groupid:5fa2d687c59139213cf8c081
user:PNZT4lvwQZPCWql6rWVEJHjt6Pe2
```

Using this nodejs code I am trying to get the query:

```
 app.get("/groups/sync", (req, res) => {
  db.collection("groups")
    .aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "peoplegroups",
          localField: "groups_id",
          foreignField: "groupid",
          as: "User",
        },
      },
    ])
    .toArray(function (err, data) {
      if (err) throw res.status(500).send(err);
      res.status(201).send(data);
    });
});
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5fa2d687c59139213cf8c082",
        "groupid": "5fa2d687c59139213cf8c081",
        "user": "PNZT4lvwQZPCWql6rWVEJHjt6Pe2",
        "__v": 0,
        "User": [
            {
                "_id": "5fa2d687c59139213cf8c081",
                "groupname": "rsr",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": "5fa2d689c59139213cf8c083",
                "groupname": "rsrs",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": "5fa2d68ac59139213cf8c085",
                "groupname": "easa",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ]
    },
```

As you can see it returns all the peoplegroups fields instead of the matching groupid with the group_id. What is wrong??

Comment: `localField: "groups_id"` is `localField:"_id"`. But also,  they need to be the same type. Check if they are in Atlas or Compass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your `$lookup` has a bad `localField`. Following your schema should be `_id` instead of `groups_id`.

The second thing is, what are you trying to join?

Knowing an `_id` get all `peoplegroups` which `groupid` is equal to `_id`?
Or only group your `peoplegroups` by the same `groupid`?

To get the first one you need a `$match` stage before the `$lookup` like this:

```js
db.group.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "peoplegroups",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "groupid",
      "as": "User"
    }
  }
])
```

In this way you will get all users with `groupid` equal to `1`.

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_3y6iq_F76_)

But, the second option (following your query), will group different users. Look this [example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rjopwZkEJKN) to know how works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The second example is exactly what I am trying to achieve (match the groupid with the _id from the collection "group"), but it does not work when I try exactly what you did. Is this because groupid is a String and _id is an ObjectID?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. Try to set `groupid` in your schema as `ObjectId`.

Comment: Jep, that was the problem.. Pfff... Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You are welcome! Also if the answer solve your problem, mark it as accepted is appreciated